# Google protocol buffer works on windows but not in linux

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have a simple program (written in Java) which uses the google protocol buffer and it works fine on a windows machine.

But when I run it on a linux machine I get the following exception :

```
com.google.protobuf.Descriptors$FileDescriptor.internalBuildGeneratedFileFrom(Ljava/lang/String;[Lcom/google/protobuf/Descriptors$FileDescriptor;Lcom/google/protobuf/Descriptors$FileDescriptor$InternalDescriptorAssigner;
    at com.test.integration.protocols.protocolBuffers.messages.TestMsgs.<clinit>(TestMsgs.java:5111)
    at com.test.integration.protocols.protocolBuffers.messages.TestMsgs$SessionInfo.<clinit>(TestMsgs.java:3346)
    at com.test.integration.protocols.protocolBuffers.messages.TestMsgs$TestRequest.<init>(TestMsgs.java:782)
    at com.test.integration.protocols.protocolBuffers.messages.TestMsgs$TestRequest.<clinit>(TestMsgs.java:760)
    at com.test.simulators.TestJmsListener.onMessage(TestJmsListener.java:80)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dispatch(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:1215)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.dispatch(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:131)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSessionExecutor.iterate(ActiveMQSessionExecutor.java:202)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner.runTask(PooledTaskRunner.java:122)
    at org.apache.activemq.thread.PooledTaskRunner$1.run(PooledTaskRunner.java:43)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I use the same jar file for the protocol buffer in both machines.

Comment: This looks like just a part of the error message. Can you please provide the full stack trace, or better the full output of your program ?

Comment: added the full trace. This is the only output related to the problem

Comment: The error message says something about file descriptors. Perhaps you have some file paths or path handling code in the app which e.g. mixes the slash and backslash, or uses absolute paths which are only valid on one OS but not the other?

Comment: Can you please provide TestJmsListener.java? Or at least relevant part of it (around line 80)?

Comment: By the way, which exception do you get? `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`?

Comment: @vond thats exactly the exception I get ... Unfortunately I cannot post the source of my files as it is private. Thx for any help you all can give considering this limitation ...

Comment: The only thing I can suggest is to double-check that you use the same version of protobuf JAR both on Linux and on Windows, and that this version is exactly the same as of the protoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protoc and the protobuf runtime library (jar) are tightly coupled.  You cannot use an older protoc with a newer runtime nor vice versa. Please double-check that you use exactly the same version of the protobuf jar file on Windows and on Linux, and this version is the same as version of protoc you used to generate Java code.

Comment: Well after many retries I reverted everything to version 2.1.0 and it works. I accept this answer as it is correct and the closest one to my problem. (although part of my solution was reverting to an older version) Thanks !